# issue with firefox tamper data plugin

Tags: firefox-addon

[image]

I am facing this problem while debugging a website.

**Plugin** used: tamper data for fire fox;

**Possibilities**: its a ajax request.

as you see in the image the tamper dialog dose not show anything for this request. for other request it shows the general options.

any known issue with this.

And I also want to know if any other better tool available for analyzing websites(live or remote, not on localhost)

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

Tamperdata is the buggiest thing ever made, even the UI takes 50 clicks to do anything. Look for another tool. I personally use [HackBar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3899/) to send simple POST/GET requests (there's a version that can modify cookies per request too I think), and [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [livehttpheaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/) (although livehttpheaders is also buggy) when I need to analyze traffic.

Comment: how can we alter the post data in hackbar?

Comment: After a post request hit F9 then check "Enable post data". Other than that you have to manually create them. "Burp Suite" or Fiddler should work for what you want to do.